# Record incoming mjpeg stream?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming

I have a incoming mjpeg stream from an IP cam.
Now I can show it using ffmpeg and openGL, but when I tried to save all the incoming streams into a file and play it later, the player(VLC) fails to open the file.

I was told I need to add some header when I start/stop the recording to let the player know the file's format.
But I could not find any reference on this topic.
Could anyone share a example on this topic?

Comment: can you provide more detail like ffprobe results? what command are you use to record?

Comment: command line and console output please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try,

```
ffmpeg -i http://x.x.x.x/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?resolution=320x240 -an -vcodec flv file.flv
```

work for me in VLC and others players.

Comment: What does -an do ?

Comment: an = no audio, the option remove audio